# Kendo DropDownList too slow while read dataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-dropdown, kendo-multiselect

I have kendo dropdown/multiSelect... 
Each of which is linked to a controller method which returns 37,000 items...

It takes a lot of time to show data...

So,I thought We DON'T HAVE TO return 37000 items to the dropdowns.

Is it possible to stop that buffering issue??

Comment: If you have that many objects, then dropdown/multiselect is not the way to do it. You could use a multiselect with autocomplete option and show only the first _n_ results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a multiSelect consider using the MinLength option :

```
Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.ObjectID)
                    //start autocompleting only after 3 char
                    .MinLength(3)
```

And as suggested in the first comment you could also take only the first n results in the controler action.